# No simple products in order object due to grouped product extension

Tags: magento2, orders, configurable-product, simple-product, grouped-products

We are using an extension that allows us to add configurable products to a grouped product. This way all the simple variations are nicely displayed per configurable product on the grouped product product page.

The problem is that when customers order simple variations from the grouped product page they are added as a configurable product to the order instead of a simple product.

Our partner which handles delivery of the products looks at the order and tried to take out all the simple products but since the products where added as a configurable products it doesn't find any and can't process the order.

Is there a way to set these products to simple products when they are ordered from a grouped product page?